# Which material would work best as "sacrificial material" for melting aluminum powder in a kiln?

Tags: redox

I need to melt aluminum powder in a kiln, but before it melts it gets oxidized almost completely. My kiln is almost airtight, but it doesn't have inert gas inlet.
Which material would work best as sacrificial material, which would react with oxygen (and water vapor) before aluminum?

Comment: Must you use Al *powder*? Chunks of aluminum might serve, and they are protected by the surface oxide film until they melt. There is some oxidation, but nowhere near as much as from powder, with its high surface-to-volume ratio.

Comment: Yes, I must use powder.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Scavengers are a mess. Magnesium might do. Do you have a press? Just compact your sample sufficiently and you should have a lot less problems.  Other possibility: Put your kiln in a larger beaker with a lid having a hole, fill it with Argon (or nitrogen in a pinch), fill in the aluminium using a funnel, and quickly place the lid on the kiln with a pair of tweezers.

Answer (score 1):

You need some oxygen scavengers *before* you start heating up the system. However, please note that you are going to need a *lot* of scavengers. To get rid of all the oxygen, you will have to put in a large excess of these scavengers into the chamber.

There is some information on oxygen scavengers on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_scavenger)

Comment: It looks like "oxygen scavengers" are more targeted for food.  Is there anything targeted for metalwork?

Comment: Not that I know of. Mg as another comment mentions, may also be a good solution.